# Is there a way to change all imports in a project?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a big refactor in a particular repo.
As part of the refactor, I have to change all the imports.
For example:
`from a.data.const import somevar`
Need to change to:
`from b.data.const import somevar`
Of course I am familiar with the search and replace option in pycharm but I am looking for an efficient code that will scan an entire repo in one go.
Ideas?

Comment: i want it to be as clean as it can be, i want a program to rewrite all imports for me

Comment: Pycharm supports [rename refactoring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rename-refactorings.html) which will update references for you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how well you know your codebase, `sed` may do the trick...

```sh
find my_repo -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed -Ei '' 's/^from a\.data\.const import somevar/from b.data.const import somevar/' {} +
```

The `find` command will find all the files with `.py` extensions, and then the `sed` command replaces lines starting with `from a.data.const import somevar` with `from b.data.const import somevar`.

Note: if you've got a decent IDE like VSCode, then you can do a regex find-and-replace like this natively without using `find` or `sed`.

[image]

**Important** note: This approach isn't code-aware, so it will also change lines inside of multi-line strings and such.